# An error about Maven integrating tomcat running

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was using, the springmvc write demo, which USES pure annotations development, achieved AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer class was used to configure the spring container loading and was relieved from the web. The XML configuration file, I can start using tomcat server, but not using maven to integrate tomcat to start.

This is my pom.xml configuration information:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.13</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <port>80</port>
        <path>/</path>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

After the bean is accessed, an error is reported. Here is the stack information:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------< com.itxitao:springmvc_01_quickstart >-----------------
[INFO] Building springmvc_01_quickstart 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) >process-classes @ springmvc_01_quickstart >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] -- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @springmvc_01_quickstart --
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] -- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @springmvc_01_quickstart --
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) <process-classes @ springmvc_01_quickstart <<&lt;
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] -- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) @springmvc_01_quickstart --
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:80/
[INFO] Using existing Tomcat server configuration at D:\IdeaProject\springmvc\springmvc_01_quickstart\target\tomcat
[INFO] create webapp with contextPath:
On December 3, 2023 9:59:49 afternoon org. Apache. Coyote. AbstractProtocol init
Message: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
On December 3, 2023 9:59:49 afternoon org. Apache. Catalina. Core. StandardService startInternal
Information: Starting service Tomcat
On December 3, 2023 9:59:49 afternoon org. Apache. Catalina. Core. StandardEngine startInternal
Information: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
On December 3, 2023 9:59:50 afternoon org. Apache. Catalina. Core. The ApplicationContext log
Information: 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on the classpath
On December 3, 2023 9:59:50 afternoon org. Apache. Catalina. Core. The ApplicationContext log
On December 3, 2023 9:59:50 afternoon org. Apache. Catalina. Core. The ApplicationContext log
Information: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcher'
[INFO] Initializing Servlet 'dispatcher'
[INFO] Completed initialization in 421 ms
On December 3, 2023 9:59:51 afternoon org. Apache. Coyote. AbstractProtocol start
Message: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
user save ..
On December 3, 2023 10:00:35 afternoon org. Apache. Catalina. Core. StandardWrapperValve invoke
Serious: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed;  nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:  'void javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.setContentLengthLong(long)'] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.setContentLengthLong(long)'
at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse.writeHeaders(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:130)
at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse.getBody(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:96)
at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:126)
at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:44)
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:227)
at  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters (AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:293)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleRe
```

I hope that I can integrate tomcat with Maven to run the project, so that the domain name can be short and fast.